# Where can I find info on World Axis (4e) Sorrowsworn and Nightwalkers?

Tags: dnd-4e, lore

To the best of my knowledge, in 4th edition, Sorrowsworn were defined as powerful psychopomps who maintain the preservation of the cycle of death and rebirth, and/or as Exarches of the Raven Queen, and Nightwalkers were powerful "shadowy" undead (which I think wasn't that big a departure from their previous lore) but I cannot recall what books specifically talk about these entities or what they specifically say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substantial lore for the Sorrowsworn and Nightwalker appears in the following D&D 4e sourcebooks:

- *Monster Manual* p.196, p.242-243
- *Manual of the Planes* p.55-57
- *The Shadowfell: Gloomwrought and Beyond*